# Eliminating Last Comma & Space

Tags: java

Here is original prompt:

"Write a for loop to print all NUM_VALS elements of array hourlyTemp. Separate elements with a comma and space. Ex: If hourlyTemp = {90, 92, 94, 95}, print:
90, 92, 94, 95

Note that the last element is not followed by a comma, space, or newline."

Here is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class PrintWithComma {
    public static void main (String [] args) {
        final int NUM_VALS = 4;
        int[] hourlyTemp = new int[NUM_VALS];
        int i = 0;

        hourlyTemp[0] = 90;
        hourlyTemp[1] = 92;
        hourlyTemp[2] = 94;
        hourlyTemp[3] = 95;

        for (i = 0; i < NUM_VALS; i++) {
            System.out.print(hourlyTemp[i] + ", ");
        }

        System.out.println("");

        return;
    }
}
```

My output is "90, 92, 94, 95, " when it should be "90, 92, 94, 95"

How do i eliminate the last comma and space?

Comment: Add a condition to check if it is the last iteration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if the last iteration is reached. If not print the comma, otherwise don't.

Replace :

```
for (i = 0; i < NUM_VALS; i++) {
     System.out.print(hourlyTemp[i] + ", ");
}
```

With:

```
for (i = 0; i < NUM_VALS; i++) {
     if (i == (NUM_VALS - 1)) System.out.print(hourlyTemp[i]);
     else System.out.print(hourlyTemp[i] + ", ");
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Generally you don't know number of values to print up-front (but in your case it's 4). So it is easier to print separator `before` instead of `after`. No `if`s:

```
String sep="";
for (i = 0; i < NUM_VALS; i++) {
     System.out.print(sep + hourlyTemp[i]);
     sep=", ";
  }
```

Trick is - first time there is nothing to separate hence separator is empty, later - `", "`;

Fits into register, saves branch predictor's work. Calculating `if (i == last_value)` is not 0 cost as well.

Comment: That's the way I usually do it.

Comment: I like this one a lot.

Comment: Nice approach, but isn't this kind of wasteful, re-assigning `sep` each time?

Comment: Fits into register, saves branch predictor's work, i think. Calculating `if (i == last_value)` is not 0 cost as well.

Answer (score 2):

```
String delimiter = ", ";
```

The first way is using `java.util.StringJoiner`. Additionally, you may specify a prefix and suffix of a result string (for example, `(delimiter, "[", "]")`).

```
StringJoiner joiner = new StringJoiner(delimiter);
for (int i : hourlyTemp) joiner.add(Integer.toString(i));
System.out.println(joiner.toString());
```

The second way is using Stream API.

```
Arrays.stream(hourlyTemp)
            .map(i -> i.toString())
            .collect(Collectors.joining(delimiter));
```

Or the most boring way:

```
for (i = 0; i < NUM_VALS;) 
    System.out.print(hourlyTemp[i] + (i++ != (NUM_VALS - 1) ? delimiter : ""));
```

Answer (score 0):

Split up the value printing and the comma-space printing into two separate statements, and don't print the comma-space for the last value:

```
System.out.print(hourlyTemp[i]);
if (i + 1 < NUM_VALS) {
  System.out.print(", ");
}
```

Alternatively, print the first value outside the loop, then print the comma-space first inside the loop:

```
System.out.print(hourlyTemp[0]);
for (int i = 1; i < NUM_VALS; ++i) {
  System.out.print(", " + hourlyTemp[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

check if `i` has reached the last iteration.

```
for (i = 0; i < NUM_VALS; i++) {
        if (i == (NUM_VALS - 1))
            System.out.print(hourlyTemp[i]);
        else
            System.out.print(hourlyTemp[i] + ", ");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

As an example, you can put a conditional and just print a blank space once you reach the end.

```
for(int i=0; i<10; i++) {
    System.out.print(i + (i < 10-1 ? ", " : ""));
}
```